# Considering the set of integers between 77-999, inclusive, how many are divisible by no less than three of the numbers 2, 3, 6 and 8?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

I'm a bit stuck on how to approach this question. I know how to solve this for how many are divisible by ''exactly'' (and also ''at most'') three items of the given set . But the **at least/no less than** three is what confuses me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any number divisible by $2$ and by $3$ also is divisible by $6$, so it's a "good" number.  Any number not divisible by $3$ also is not divisible by $6$, so it's a "bad" number.  Any number not divisible by $2$ also is not divisible by $6$ or by $8$, so it's also a "bad" number.  Put these results together and it's very easy to characterize the "good" numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Following the ideas of Robert, I'll provide a solution.
Consider the list $\lbrace 77,78,\dots,1000\rbrace$. Say a number is "good" if it is divisible by at least three of the numbers $2,3,6,8$. If $2$, or $3$, does not divide a number, neither does $6$, so such a number cannot be good, as there are at least two numbers from our list not dividing. Thus, we are only interested in numbers divisible by $2$, and by $3$ - but such numbers are also divisible by $6$, so three of our numbers do divide. We have thus characterized the good numbers completely as the numbers divisible by $6$, i.e. set $\lbrace 78,84,\dots,996\rbrace$. This is every sixth number in our set, i.e. we get $\lfloor \frac{1000-76}{6}\rfloor = 154$ as our answer.

Answer (score 1):

“No less than three” means the same as “at least three”.  So a number that meets your inclusion criterion must

- be divisible by three of the numbers, *or*
- be divisible by all four of the numbers (or equivalently, be divisible by their lowest common multiple, which is 24).